# Define product derivative

Tags: function-construction, calculus-and-analysis, functional-style

How do I define the $n$th product derivative of a function in *Mathematica*?

The first product derivative $f^\ast$ of a function $f$ is
$$
f^\ast(x)=\exp\left(\frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}\right)
$$
The $n$th product derivative is the result of applying this operator $n$ times.

This is my attempt at a recursive definition:

```
In[111]:= Clear[prodd]
prodd[f_, n_] := prodd[e^(f'/f), n - 1]; prodd[f_, 0] = f

Out[112]= f


In[113]:= prodd[E^x, 1](* Should print E *)

Out[113]= e^(E^-x Derivative[1][(E^x)])

In[114]:= prodd[E^E^x, 1](* Should print E^E^x *)

Out[114]= e^(E^-E^x Derivative[1][(E^E^x)])

In[114]:= prodd[E^x, 2](* Should print 1 *)
```

Comment: As an aside, what is the product derivative used for?

Comment: @rcollyer: see the preprint by Mike Spivey that I linked to. See also [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10851-011-0275-1), [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10511979908965937), and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2007.03.081).

Comment: @J.M. the preprint is awesome. I like the exponential approximations, and it makes me wonder what else I've missed in calculus, or was ignored ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From Corollary 1 of [this preprint](http://www.math.ups.edu/~mspivey/ProdCalc.pdf) by Mike Spivey, there is a simple nonrecursive definition for the product derivative:

```
ProductD[f_, x_] := ProductD[f, {x, 1}];
ProductD[f_, {x_, k_Integer?NonNegative}] := Exp[D[Log[f], {x, k}]]
```

Verify a few identities:

```
ProductD[f[x] g[x], x] == ProductD[f[x], x] ProductD[g[x], x] // Simplify
   True

ProductD[x^a, x] == Exp[a/x]
   True

ProductD[Exp[Exp[x]], x] == Exp[Exp[x]]
   True

ProductD[x^x, x] == E x
   True
```

---

Here's the corresponding multiplicative calculus analog of `Derivative[]`:

```
ProductDerivative[0] = Identity;
ProductDerivative[k_Integer?Positive][f_] := 
             Derivative[k][Composition[Log, f]] /. Function[ff_] :> Function[Evaluate[E^ff]]
```

To use the example given by the OP in the comments:

```
ProductDerivative[1][Sin][4]
   E^Cot[4]

ProductDerivative[1][Sin[#] &][4]
   E^Cot[4]

ProductDerivative[1][Function[u, Sin[u]]][4]
   E^Cot[4]
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should have tried to find an explicit definition first.

Comment: Is there a way to make this return a function? For example, `ProductD[Sin[x], {x, 1}][4]` should evaluate to `E^Cot[4]`.

Comment: I've added an implementation of `ProductDerivative[]` now.

Answer (score 7):

`e` is not the same as `E`, and `f'` expects `f` to be a function but `E^x` is just an expression, so I use `D[f, x]` instead:

```
Clear[prodd]
prodd[f_, n_] := prodd[E^(D[f, x]/f), n - 1];
prodd[f_, 0] := f

prodd[E^x, 1](*Should print E*)

prodd[E^E^x, 1](*Should print E^E^x*)

prodd[E^x, 2](*Should print 1*)
```

> ```
> E
>
> E^E^x
>
> 1
> ```

You could also write:

```
Clear[prodd]

prodd[f_, n_] := Nest[E^(D[#, x]/#) &, f, n]
```

If you are going to use `x` in this manner I recommend using `\[FormalX]` instead to prevent failure if you accidentally assign a value to `x`.

You might also consider something like this:

```
Clear[prodd]

prodd[f_, n_] := Nest[E^(#'[\[FormalX]]/#[\[FormalX]]) &, f, n]

prodd[E^# &, 1]

prodd[E^E^# &, 1]

prodd[E^# &, 2]
```

> ```
> E
>
> E^E^x
>
> 1
> ```