# How do I make an operator that acts on a function with the function's argument explicitly given?

Tags: functions, operators

I am trying to make a finite difference operator such that it would behave similar to the partial derivative $\partial_{x}f[x]$.

$\delta_n[f[n],m] := \frac{f[n+m]-f[n]}{m}\ .$

I couldn't find a way to define it where I can just pass the function with its argument explicitly shown to the operator. Note that I don't want to give the operator just the name of the function, that's because it cannot act on the function twice if I define it that way, e.g.

$\delta_n[\delta_n[f[n],m],m]\ .$

The finite difference operator is just an example. My goal is to learn how to do it so I could apply this to my work in general.

Edit:

I found a partial solution with the following lines of code

SetAttributes[$\delta$, HoldAll]
$\delta[f\_[n\_],m\_]:=\frac{f[n+m]-f[n]}{m}\ .$

There is still a problem when I do the operation twice, or directly pass the expression of the function into the operator, i.e.

$\delta[n^2,m]$

or if the function has multiple variables,

$\delta[f[n,l],m]\ .$

It would be nice if it could just work like the Derivative operator.

Comment: Before anything else, have you already seen `DifferenceQuotient[]`?

Comment: No, I have not, but I would like to learn how to implement it so that I can define any arbitrary operator on a function. It was just a simple example that I came up with.

Comment: One problem with wanting something like $\delta[n^2, m]$ to work is that you'd actually need to specify what the variables were somewhere. Note that when taking the derivative, you need to write `D[n^2, n]` so that Mathematica knows what to take the derivative with respect to. (Otherwise it might be `Power`, or even `2`.) So you need to find a way to give Mathematica this info—either by having extra arguments/options, feeding in functions/bound variables instead (e.g. `d[n |-> n^2, m |-> m]`), marking them somehow, or declaring specific variables to be arguments globally (which might be odd).

Comment: You might also be interested in how I implemented the product derivative in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13389), as a guide on how to implement operators.

Comment: Thank you @J.M.! What I needed to do was simply to convert the input function to a pure function.

Comment: And thank you, @thorimur, for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
FiniteD[f_,{n_,m_}] := (Function[n,f][n+m] - Function[n,f][n])/m
```